# Can't buy filters in Riga

Tags: metro-2033

Having messed up my first attempt at completing metro 2033 because I ran out of filters, I decided to make buying filters an absolute priority in my next attempt. I heard that the only two places where I can buy good quality filters are Riga and Polis. Now I'm in Riga, I found the small armoury and can see a cluster of filters on the shelf. However, none of the traders will sell them to me. All they offer me is ammo, weapons and medkits. Why can't I buy any filters?